# Is there a single word for "not pregnant"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a single word that is the antonym for "pregnant" to describe someone "not pregnant"?

Comment: Yes: *unoccupied*.

Comment: Language is about the combination of words in infinitely many permutations.  This constant search for single words for everything is silly.

Comment: It can never be casually described as this is priviledged information and would therefore require consent before being disclosed as it cannot be assumed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Unpregnant](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unpregnant): (from Collins Dict.)

> - (biology) not pregnant; not carrying a fetus in the womb.

Comment: +1@Josh61, occured to me too.. Not pregnant; not quickened: with of.Not quick of wit; dull. (from Wiktionary) . nullipara or nulligravida -never pregnant

Comment: There is _nonpregnant_ also.

Comment: *A very very happy unpregnancy, to you! To you!*

Answer (score 4):

Nongravid means not pregnant according to the Merriam Webster dictionary

http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/nongravid

Answer (score 2):

**Nulligravida** describes a woman who has never been pregnant. I don't know if there is a term for a woman who has had children but isn't pregnant at the moment.

Comment: Perhaps, in the same vein, nongravida?

Answer (score 1):

In Sequence:

"Unpregnant" may become a primigravida (pregnant for the first time) but a primi'da can 
 not be called a nulligravida.

Answer (score -1):

**Nullipara**

> a woman who has never given birth to a child

— http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/nullipara

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts. This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective and could be improved by adding [references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/59/77227).

Comment: A woman might be pregnant even if she has never given birth.

Comment: A woman might have given birth and no longer be pregnant.